# BASH Script - connect via ssh and run a mysql command

Tags: mysql, bash, ssh

I'm trying to create a simple bash script that will ping a number of clients. If the client is not reachable, then it should launch an update on a db on another server... I have a passwordless ssh access to the db server, so i was trying to do the following:

```
for i in {11..25}
do
        if      ping -q -c 1 192.168.42.$i > /dev/null 2>&1
        then
                echo 1
        else
                ip=192.168.42.$i
                ssh admin@192.168.3.240 "mysql  -u parkuser -ppass -e 'update SMARTPARK.client SET online=0 where SMARTPARK.ip_client=$ip'"
        fi

done
```

I'm getting a `bash: mysql: command not found` error when using it... Obviously mysql is installed on the db server

Comment: ssh login in without password, mysql has it

Comment: your update will fail anyways. `... ip_client=192.168.42.11` is invalid and will cause a syntax error at the sql level.

Comment: you are right... do I have to use single quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work fine for me. Since you're getting a command not found error, perhaps it is a problem with your `$PATH` on ssh. Try connecting manually, and running `which mysql` to get the full path to the executable. In my case, it's `/usr/bin/mysql`, then you might try using that in your statement, such as:

```
ssh admin@192.168.3.240 "/usr/bin/mysql -u parkuser -ppass -e 'update SMARTPARK.client SET online=0 where SMARTPARK.ip_client=$ip '"
```

Answer (score 1):

you've got single quotes inside single quotes, it should be single inside double:

```
ssh admin@192.168.3.240 "mysql  -u parkuser -ppass -e 'update SMARTPARK.client SET online=0 where SMARTPARK.ip_client=$ip '"
```